# PHP Mail not sending function output

Tags: php, wordpress, sendmail

On my WordPress site I am trying to mail() the output of a function however it is failing to return the output but will return hard coded outputs placed inside the while loop.

Essentially what I am asking is what in this code is wrong and how do I fix it. I would rather be tutored in what I have done wrong than *"Have fixed code; copy and paste"* if at all possible.

*I am purposely trying to stay away from inbuilt WordPress functions and calls*

**EDIT**:
When I `echo $string;` it displays with the expected output formatted as I intended, with the exclusion of the contents between `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`.

The functions are fetching the data properly it just is not being included in the email to be sent out, which is being sent it just appears blank. When sent as plaintext the email contents are as follows

> `<html><br /><br /></html>`

[Updated Code](http://pastebin.com/UYgbCYa8)

I just inspected the output of the code, with the intent of displaying it to you so you can see the outcome and I noticed that this is included in-place of all the outputted emails, due to a "bonus feature" of one of my plugins, I am not sure which one, as this is nothing I have coded. Included inline due to not meeting reputation requirements to post more than two hyperlinks.

> `<p>ward@halifaxonline.com.au<script type="text/javascript">
>   /* <![CDATA[ */
>   (function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");a=l.className;if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
>   /* ]]> */
>   </script><br> <br>
>   </p>`

To the best of my knowledge scripts cannot be run in emails, but surely this would not cause a failure to display the rest of the code, just render the scripts useless.

[Expected Output](http://pastebin.com/9QvCxmdJ)

Comment: Which function(s) is misbehaving?

Comment: Please insert relevant code snippets inside the question itself as well, for the record, and to make it easier for users to see what might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 34:

```
mail($to, 'Test', $string, $headers) ;
```

should be

```
$sent = mail($to, 'Test', $string, $headers) ;
```

That's why it keeps saying the mail is not sent. It has been sent but you didn't set the variable you are checking.

Comment: I am aware of that, I removed that thinking that the variable may not be being called.

Comment: Your code is too long and messy to wade through in an attempt to fix your problem. I recommend you try to narrow it down by checking what it is doing after every step by outputting to the browser. Then when you've narrowed it down you can post a new question with the specifics. Right now it's just a big mess of someone else's code that doesn't work.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by my code being messy, I have tried to keep it as simple as I can however I am relatively new to coding and as such haven't mastered writing the most elegant code yet.

Have you any suggestions on how to de mess it?

Comment: I mean more that you've just directed people to an entire script where there is somewhere an error, instead of narrowing it down to ask a specific question, which is the reason why you haven't received many responses.

Comment: I thought the question was self evident; "What is wrong with this code?"

When I `echo` it, it displays but when I email it; nothing.